# Is ことのある the same as ことがある?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I was trying to understand this sentence:

それは聞いたことのない少女の声であった。

And I found [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/69368/what-does-verb%e3%81%93%e3%81%a8%e3%81%ae%e3%81%82%e3%82%8bnoun-mean).

The answerer changed ことのある to ことがある, stating that "の is used as a subject marker in some cases."

Does this mean I can treat ことのある and ことがある as roughly the same? (の and が are being used to identify a subject)?

Comment: You can't treat them the same generally.  But の works as the subject marker within a relative clause, which is the situation you have here.